# power query: convert a value of Function output to Text

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

i wrote 2 power query functions and main function will have a sub function (with input argument):

```
### main query - Query1 ###
let
    my = Query2, ===> no error until here
    K = Text.Split(my, ",") ===> Error occurred at this place
in
    K
 
### sub query - Query2 ###
let
    output =
        (AccountID as text) as text =>
        let
            x = AccountID
        in
            x
in
    output
```

My idea is to call main query which parses the sub query function *Query2* (input argument for example **Hello,World**) and print the output from it, but it throws an error

> Error: We cannot convert a value of type Function to type Text.

```
let
    my = Query2
in
    my
```

input prompt works fine for above main function query and it just prints the input argument i pass. but issue is at line ==> K = Text.Split(my, ",") which i am not sure how to convert that function output to a text format.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?  Query2 wants an input and you are not providing thst when calling from Query1

Comment: it will prompt for input if i just pass the my = Query2, but i want to slice/print the output of Query2, hence getting error due to K = Text.Split(my, ",") in Query1

Comment: I have updated my question about input prompt behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**my = Query2**  generates nothing since the function is written as

```
(AccountID as text) as text =>
```

and that **requires** being called with input, like

```
= Query2("123456")
```

Query1 doesnt provide that input, so nothing is returned for the next step and thus the next step generates an error

You can see this by clicking on step one of Query1 on the right side of screen. It just shows the function, not the result of the function

[image]

Comment: Understood.. thanks @horseyride .. well explained